# SQL - Order to 3 results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have little question. How to do in SQL server sorting and return it to variables (outputs)
I know how can I do this in MySQL, but not sure about MSSQL,since there isn´t limit function.
For example :

```
DECLARE @dwFirst = SELECT * FROM RANK ORDER BY dwPoints DESC (WHERE dwPoints will be best)
DECLARE @dwSecond, etc.
```

Edit : Thanks, but this SELECT TOP works just for one result.

21000 - [SQL Server]Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

It says when I use TOP 2, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use `offset / fetch first row only`:

```
DECLARE @dwFirst = (SELECT <column>
                    FROM RANK
                    (WHERE dwPoints will be best)
                    ORDER BY dwPoints DESC 
                    OFFSET 0 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
                   );
```

You can change the offset to get additional values from subsequent rows.

However, I might suggest conditional aggregation:

```
select @dwFirst = max(case when seqnum = 1 then col end),
       @dwSecond = max(case when seqnum = 2 then col end),
       @dwThird = max(case when seqnum = 3 then col end)       
from (select col, row_number() over (order by dwpoints desc) as seqnum
      from . . .
     ) t;
```

That way, you only run the query once to assign all the variables.

Comment: I love both of these options. I didn't realize offset / fetch was new to 2012.  I could use that conditional aggregation trick in the future.  Thanks Gordon!

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server as the `TOP` function.  You will want to use it with the `ORDER BY` so you get consistent results

```
 DECLARE @dwFirst int
 SET @dwFirst = (SELECT TOP 1 dwPoints FROM RANK ORDER BY dwPoints DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have a single variable but a select statement can return more then one value and also multiple columns. So you need to select a single value in and also specify which column its coming from!

```
DECLARE @dwFirst varchar(50) --or whatever data type
Select @dwFirst = top 1 dwpoints FROM RANK ORDER BY dwPoints DESC
```